# Tips and fix on why this Bootstrap toggle hide/show is not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just finished my bootstrap toggle hide/show and it all works great except the function of viewen the different content, all together is very edgy and not smooth at all.. the borders jump around when activating the toggle etc..

My bet would be that it must be something odd with the script... dont know what do, i hope someone can help.

```js
$('.testver a i').on('click', function(e) {
  var currTarget = $(this).closest('a').data('target').substr(1);
  $('#leftpanel').find('[id^="demo"]').not(currTarget).collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
#leftpanel {position: relative; }
#leftpanel h1 {font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Montserrat bold'; color:#b0a887; border-top: 1px solid #eee; font-style: normal;}
#leftpanel h2 {font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Montserrat bold'; color:#b0a887;  font-style: normal;}
#leftpanel a {margin-left: 230px; position: relative; top: -40px; right: -100px;}
#demo1, #demo2, #demo3, #demo4 { color: #333; font-size: 14px; margin-top: -40px; margin-right: 5px; font-family: 'Myriad Pro 31655';}



.collapse {}
.testver { width: 370px;}

.testver hr {


}

.fa-angle-up {
  display: none;
}

.testver i {

}

 .testver .fa {
   right:
 }

 .arrow[aria-expanded="true"] .fa-angle-up {
   display: inline-block;
 }

  .arrow[aria-expanded="true"] .fa-angle-down {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="leftpanel">
                <div class="testver">
                    <h1>Never seen before</h1>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div id="demo1" class="collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
                        text
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="testver">
                    <h2>Art and technology</h2>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
                        text
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="testver">
                    <h2>Authenticity</h2>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
                        text
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="testver">
                    <h2>Level of detail</h2>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div id="demo4" class="collapse">
                        text
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `margin-top:-40px`

You should remove gap with another trick such as `margin-bottom: -20px` to `<h1>`
and remove this line from `<a>` `top: -40px`